# trim down selection area of selected item listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a listview with buttons.Whenever I press a button I get the selected item in my view model,based on that I do my view model operation.My problem is if I click outside the item also the button gets selected as the rectangular area for selection is bigger than my button.

[image]

How can I trim down the selection area equal to my items size?

Comment: Why you put your buttons in `ListView`? Why not in panel?

Comment: What event are you using to catch the button clicks? if this is a routed event try using `OriginalSource` to trace back to the source that originated the event

Comment: The purpose of putting them in a listview was to get the value of text on it and filter a list based on that text..Sounds like a bad idea now. Can you suggest some way ,I have to bind lot of these buttons to commands in viewmodel which will set the corresponding text for search criteria.I didnt want to use lot of relay commands just for  changing a text,other way I can see is to use command parameter but for unit testing purpose I dont want to use it either.Please suggest best way to achieve this with less code and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, there is a property on most collection controls that makes a whole row selectable and I suspect that you *might* have set it. If you have set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`, *that* is your problem. Remove this property to remove the extra selectable area.

Alternatively, you can add this into the `Resources` section to remove the default blue colour all together, or change it to a different colour:

For `Background`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

For `Foreground`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
```

Comment: I dont have HorizontalContentAlignment=Strecth,but still it shows the same.Also if I do the system color trick ,the color might not be visible but button will get selected even if user click just outside its boundary.